# how to get the max date in the results of the query

Tags: sql

I have my result of the query like:

```
empName project leavedate
abc     pjt1    10/10/2013
abc     pjt1    10/12/2013
abc     pjt2    10/10/2011
```

Based on the above query result I want to get the latest date for each project on which he has taken leave.It is not table it is query results.

Comment: can u share what u tried?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(leavedate) FROM my_table_;
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_max.asp

Comment: The OP asks "for each project".  Possible better answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20651188/558639

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.empName, t1.project, t1.leavedate
FROM <yourTable> t1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM <yourTable> t2 
                  WHERE t1.project = t2.project AND t2.leavedate > t1.leavedate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
  SELECT empName, project, MAX(leavedate)
    FROM mytable
GROUP BY project;
```

Comment: You forgot **empName** in `GROUP BY`.

Comment: I believe that depends on whether project is unique or not (and, secondarily, which dialect of sql the OP is using).